# Correct tag elasticsearch

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, meta, elasticsearch

Someone created the tag [elastic-search](/questions/tagged/elastic-search), but it should be 'elasticsearch' [as per the name of the product](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).  Then when I tried to create it, the stupid heuristic refused to let me because of the other tag.

Please create the correct tag, and synonym the one with the dash to it.  There are only three posts to change right now.

Comment: Ummm, for those of you closing this as "pertains only to a specific site" - this is tagged with [tag:meta] and actually talked about a tag that existed here on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right you are, fixed on the existing posts.